# Equivalent of web partial in Android

Tags: android, gridview, partials

I am more familiar with web, but I am programming an Android app.

This is a beginner question, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around reusable views in Android. On the web, I would create a partial view and pass parameters to be added via a templating language. What is the best way to do this on Android?

More specifically, I am trying to add a grid view where each slot of the grid has an image and a subtitle with a border. I want to dynamically load the image and subtitle from the database, and add an unknown number of images to the grid.

How could I create a view to hold the images and subtitles and then dynamically load them into the grid with different data?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a GridView programatically:

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/705639/how-to-create-gridview-in-android-programaticall

This should help you with the skeleton and you can add an ImageView and TextView as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

> How could I create a view to hold the images and subtitles and then dynamically load them into the grid with different data?

You need a `GridView` and an `Adapter` to load the items dynamically into your grid. I can't post the code actually here, because it would be a very long answer. But [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_grid_view.htm) is a nice tutorial to get you started. In the example, there is a grid build with dynamic images showing step by step what you're looking for.